# Strange deadlock with `static` function or not

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, deadlock

I have two days to research read-write-lock related stuff.
And I have encountered a problem because of the virtual thread limit of GCD: [Dead Lock With `dispatch_barrier`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341738/dead-lock-with-dispatch-barrier)

Then I try to use the `pthread_rwlock_t` to implement rwlock. It's running ok like the end of the article upon.

**But** when I want to move the init code of `pthread_rwlock_t` to a `static` function like the code below, I found it enter deadlock again.

Then I thinking for a long time and debugging, I find a strange thing: 
When I move out the init code(also contain `dispatch_once`) from `static` function. Everything is ok. it's so strange, and I think it's not because of the virtual thread limit of GCD. @originaluser2

```
#import <pthread.h>

#define THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(x_) do { \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic push"); \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wunused-variable\""); \
volatile int res = (x_); \
assert(res == 0); \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic pop"); \
} while (0)

static pthread_rwlock_t kRWLock(){
    static pthread_rwlock_t _rwlock;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_init(&_rwlock, NULL));
    });
    return _rwlock;
}

//#define WILLDEADLOCK  //define it will see the deadlock demo

- (void)test
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue =  dispatch_queue_create("com.test.testasync", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<5000; i++) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
#ifdef WILLDEADLOCK
            pthread_rwlock_t rwlock = kRWLock();
#else
            static pthread_rwlock_t rwlock;
            static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
            dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
                THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_init(&rwlock, NULL));
            });
#endif
            THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock));
            NSLog(@"rlock1");
            NSLog(@"runlock1");
            THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock));

            if (i%100==0) {
                THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock));
                NSLog(@"wlock1");
                NSLog(@"wunlock1");
                THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock));
            }
        });
    }

    dispatch_barrier_sync(queue, ^{});
    NSLog(@"completed");
}
```

Comment: When you answer your own question here, enter it below as an actual answer. A couple days later you can "accept" your answer to let people know it's solved.

Comment: @Almo Sorry, I have not been authorized to write answers for some reasons.. so I must update the answer in the post.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it as an answer for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Note: The author of this question wasn't allowed to post his answer as an answer, so I've done it for him.

---

This is a stupid question. I forgot the `pthread_rwlock_t` is a `struct` and it will be copied to a new memory after `return`.

The correct code below:

```
#import <pthread.h>

#define THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(x_) do { \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic push"); \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wunused-variable\""); \
volatile int res = (x_); \
assert(res == 0); \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic pop"); \
} while (0)

static pthread_rwlock_t *kRWLock(){
    static pthread_rwlock_t _rwlock;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_init(&_rwlock, NULL));
    });
    return &_rwlock;
}

- (void)test
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue =  dispatch_queue_create("com.test.testasync", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<5000; i++) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            pthread_rwlock_t *rwlock = kRWLock();

            THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_rdlock(rwlock));
            NSLog(@"rlock1");
            NSLog(@"runlock1");
            THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_unlock(rwlock));

            if (i%100==0) {
                THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_wrlock(rwlock));
                NSLog(@"wlock1");
                NSLog(@"wunlock1");
                THREAD_ASSERT_ON_ERROR(pthread_rwlock_unlock(rwlock));
            }
        });
    }

    dispatch_barrier_sync(queue, ^{});
    NSLog(@"completed");
}
```